# Error installing SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I keep getting the following error when trying to install SQL Server 2008 R2, during the Server Configuration Screen:

> The full-text service account must be a domain account on windows 2003
>   domain controller.

I have tried putting in a active directory user/password, as well as NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM, but the same error comes up for both

please help

Answer (score 1):

removed the username, left it blank and it went through.